# Typescript lambdas and closure (scope)

Tags: lambda, typescript, closures

I load some data for multiple users and I want to store it into a javascript array. 
In pure typescript, I will write it like that:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   promise[i] = httpquery.then( 
     (data) => { this.usersData[i] = data }
   );
)

...

this.$q.all[promise].then(......
```

unfortunately, my typescript lambda protect only this (and not the variable i). So in my case it will always store the data in this.usersData[5].

Right, I need a closure, and what lambda expression do is a bit similar to a closure as far as I understand this typescript's part of language.

so let try to do something with Typescript :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   promise[i] = (index = i) => {
       return httpquery.then( 
          (data) => { this.usersData[index] = data }
       );
   }();
)
```

which not work at all (not even compile). Why ? because seems that () => {} is not really a function. I solved this by using this way :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var getData = (index = i) => {
       return httpquery.then( 
          (data) => { this.usersData[index] = data }
       );
   };
   promise[i] = getData();
)
```

which I found not super beautiful :-p.
So my question is: how to proceed in this case of issue ? Like I did ? Or there is a way to use the lambda in typescript in a more beautiful way ? 
And why

```
 () => {}()
```

isn't working but

```
 var test = () => {}; 
 test();
```

works ? It it because of the typescript compiler which is not "smart" enough to understand that the lambda is a function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why:

```
promise[i] = (index = i) => {
  return httpquery.then( 
    (data) => { this.usersData[index] = data }
  );
}();
```

doesn't *parse* is because it isn't valid JavaScript (`var x = a => { return a + 1; }(3)` is a `SyntaxError` in JavaScript as well as TypeScript.  Simply wrapping the lambda in parenthesis is enough to make it a valid expression.

However, simply doing that will not fix your capturing issue - default arguments are evaluated on each call, and so they will all point at the final bound value of the `var`.

Instead you can either:

A) Switch to using `let` in your initializer (in which case TypeScript will automatically do the right thing:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  promise[i] = httpquery.then(data => this.usersData[i] = data);
}
```

B) Manually create the closure yourself:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  promise[i] = (index => httpquery.then(data => this.usersData[index] = data))(i);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, using let is the most beautiful solution. I still use var and didn't take the time to look at let/const, and I think is the right time to change this bad habit.
Thanks !